# Is the value of the inductor important in chua's circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, components, component-selection, autonomous

In [*Kennedy 92*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e385/fbd99486bc436f472c53ce12d1f69367c103.pdf), the author gives a worked example of Chua's circuit experiment. The circuit diagram is given below:
[image]

The author (in section 7.1) discuss how the value of each component might be chosen, **except the inductor L**. He uses an 18mH inductor. I don't know how he chooses this value.

**What if I use a 15mH inductor instead, but keep everything else the same as the article? Will it still work?** I cannot buy 18mH inductors...

Comment: Should be fine. Lot's [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=chua%27s+circuit&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=chua%27s+circuit&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5871j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=chua%27s+circuit&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpwOLKsrvjAhVW7nMBHeomA0YQ_AUIECgB&biw=1054&bih=612) and there are numerous single op amp implementations offered such as [here](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/~mcc/chaos_new/Chua.html) and [?same? cct with discussion](http://davbucci.chez-alice.fr/index.php?argument=elettronica/chua/chua.inc)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is within the linked PDF file.

> This will be our starting point too, but with a slight difference. Electronic components are available "off-the-shelf" in standard values; 7.13 mH, 5.56 nF, 50nF, and 1428Ω are not standadrd values. Therefore, we choose 18mH, 10nF, 100nF, and 18000&Omega as a nearby "standard" value starting point.

Wouldn't a 15mH inductor be more "nearby" to 7.13 mH than 18 mH?

But why not simulate the circuit in LTspice or in Falstad?